# Besides the main battery, do any components inside MacBooks rely on any other batteries to operate?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

Besides the main battery used to power Apple notebooks, do current MacBooks have any other built-in non-rechargeable batteries that may need to be replaced after a certain period of time? I was thinking particularly about the SMC; I wasn't sure if that required any external power (other than the main MacBook battery) to function.

Comment: this [SMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Controller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one battery in any modern Apple Laptop, and so far as I remember, there have never been other batteries in any Apple laptops.

The PowerPC iMac and other [PowerPC G3/G4 tower CPUs](http://www.macusersguide.com/tag/powermac-g3/) did require a [button battery replacement](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6119893) for the internal clock. I replaced many of these batteries back in the day.